# How to fix Flutter error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am working on a Flutter project using Android studio, when I build my app, i get the following errors

How can I fix this issue arising from my Flutter project? Thanks as you help!

```
C:\Projects\Nexthour Mobile App Flutter Files\.dart_tool\package_config.json does not exist.
Did you run this command from the same directory as your pubspec.yaml file?


> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Try flutter clean

Comment: I can't find flutter on my tools list in android studio! How can i access this